# Efficient way to index a list with a numpy bool array in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

As in the title, what is the most efficient way to index a `list` `l` having a `(n,)` boolean `ndarray` `ar` with `len(l) == ar.shape[0]`?

Comment: Unless `ar` is very sparse, I doubt you can get much faster than casting to array first `np.array(l)[ar]`

Comment: You can time it yourself. Have a look at [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html). The answer will probably vary depending on the size of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's make a list of idioms you could try. Time them you'll have to do yourself, because it will depend on the sizes and also the sparsity of `ar`, cf. @Imanol Luengo's comment

```
np.array(l)[ar] # output is an array
[e for e,m in zip(l, ar) if m]
[l[i] for i in np.where(ar)[0]]
```